# How to put target="_blank" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I tried many variations to put `target="_blank"` in links with jQuery, but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
var thumbfile = "<?php echo $smit_iturl_v; ?>";
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var actualHost = jQuery.trim(jQuery.url.attr("host"));
    jQuery("a img").each(function (i) {

        if (jQuery.trim(jQuery.url.setUrl(jQuery(this).attr("src")).attr("host")) == actualHost &&      
            (jQuery.url.setUrl(jQuery(this).attr("src")).attr("path")).indexOf("wp-content") != -1 &&

            isImage(jQuery.url.setUrl(jQuery(this).attr("src")).attr("file"))) {

            var parentTag = jQuery(this).parent().get(0).tagName;
            parentTag = parentTag.toLowerCase();

            if (parentTag == "a" &&
            jQuery.url.setUrl(jQuery(this).parent().attr("href")).attr("host") == actualHost &&
            jQuery.url.setUrl(jQuery(this).parent().attr("href")).attr("path").indexOf("wp-content") != -1 &&
            isImage(jQuery(this).parent().attr("href"))) {

                var description = (jQuery(this).attr("alt") == "") ? jQuery(this).attr("title") : jQuery(this).attr("alt");
                jQuery(this).parent().attr("href", thumbfile +
                        "?title=" + jQuery(this).attr("title") +
                        "&description=" + description +
                        "&url=" + stripDomain(jQuery(this).parent().attr("href"))

                );
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 84):

Too much information! This should work fine:

```
$("a").attr("target","_blank");
```

See the example here http://jsbin.com/evexi/edit. It works perfectly.

Comment: If you only want to open external links in a new window then this regex might be helpful. `$("a[href^='http']").attr('target','_blank');`

Comment: I wrote this a while back, but just used it yet again myself for a new site I'm working on: http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-jquery-selector-for-external-and.html

Answer (score 16):

Since you are iterating over the image elements that are childs of an anchor, at the beginning of the loop you can set it:

```
//...
jQuery("a img").each(function (i) {
  // 'this' is the img element, you should get the parent anchor
  jQuery(this).parent().attr('target', '_blank'); 
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 11):

To add to the awesome simplicity of this answer, which was super helpful by the way, you can target multiple types of links for example:

```
$("#whatever_id a, #another_id, #yet_another, #etc").attr("target","_blank");
```

Just keep the different id's separated by commas.

Answer (score 10):

You could give all the links you want to open in a new window a class, eg 'target-blank';

```
<a href='#' class='any existing classes target-blank'>Opens in a new window</a>
```

then add a drop of jQuery

```
$("a.target-blank").attr('target','_blank');
```

valid xhtml and a DOM that understands target='_blank'!